# -bash: chattr: command not found

Tags: permissions

I am trying to change my `.bash_profile` and it spits back

> error writing to .bash_profile Permission denied

So, I use the `chattr -i .bash_profile` to make it immutable and it gives me

> -bash: chattr: command not found.

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: `chattr` is a Linux-specific command. What system are you using? What tool are you using to try to modify this file? Have you already tried `chmod`? And finally, why is this tagged `ruby-on-rails`?

Comment: @GregHewgill Doesn't make any sense to me either. Probably belongs on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) anyway.

Comment: I am a newbie so navigating this territory is still new to me....sorry for the confusion. I am just trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 6):

If you use Ubuntu or Debian you can use

```
apt-get install e2fsprogs
```

Then you try again.

Comment: and for centos 7: "yum install e2fsprogs"

Comment: I have install e2fsprogs on Centos, but it doesn't work yet.I can't use chattr command.

Comment: @Pozzo-Balbi Finally, thank you! Redhat / Amazon Linux 1 in my case.

Comment: @jlucky It's there for me...

Answer (score 3):

Why do you assume, from that message, that the file is "immutable" and needs you to do a `chattr -i`?

You haven't given quite enough information to tell what the problem is, but my first thoughts are that 1) the file is not owned by you (created while su'ed or sudo'ed, perhaps), or 2) the permissions don't allow you to write to the file.

If you are indeed the owner (or can do a `chown` to make yourself the owner, assuming that's appropriate) try doing `chmod u+w` on it.

Answer (score 3):

This will install `chattr`: `apt-get install e2fsprogs`

Answer (score 1):

Okay I am not sure if this will help since the question of what OS was being used was not answered but I encountered a similar issue working within FreeBSD where the Man Pages seem to imply that FreeBSD supports chattr as well as lsattr however when you try to use either one you get the "command not found" error which makes it a bit confusing.

Still after some extensive digging I found the following and this may solve this problem as well or if not at least perhaps point someone in the right direction

FreeBSD offers write protection by using the special bit called Immutable to turn this on you do the following command:

```
$ chflags schg filename
```

To test to see if this flag is set you do the following command:

```
$ ls -lo filename
```

Which gets you the following results:

```
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel  schwa  12 Nov 16 15:36 filename
```

To clear or remove the file Immutable bit you do the following:

```
$ chflags noschg filename
```

Now the file can be deleted

Note: This Immutable flag can only be set by the root user.

Further chflags supports a few other interesting flags:

- arch   : Set the Archived flag
- nodump : Set the No Dump flag
- sapped : Set the System Append-Only flag
- schg   : Set the System Immutable flag
- sunlnk : Set the System Undeletable flag
- uappnd : Set the User Append-Only flag
- uchg   : Set the User Immutable flag
- uunlnk : Set the User Undeletable flag

Note: Putting a "no" before an option causes the flag to be turned off

So if you do not have access to chattr and lsattr then perhaps it is because they use this methodology to do the same thing.

P.S.  If a file has been made Immutable or Append-Only it cannot be deleted until that attribute of the file has been changed.  Not sure about any of the other settings but that was the information stated about these two.

Answer (score 0):

That "Permission denied"-error might result from you not having sufficient permissions under the classical UNIX permission model.

Immutability (and this specific file-attribute-system) is a Linux specificity. Chattr is not contained in coreutils, so you might need to install it seperately (how to do this depends on your Linux distribution).

Also, `chattr -i` will *remove* the immutability-flag, not set it.

Comment: I am attempting to teach my self ruby on rails by watching the following tutorial. In it his trying to export a PATH and that leads to this question. It's around 7 min 30s....http://www.lynda.com/home/Player.aspx?lpk4=75150&playChapter=False